# boost .h file not found while trying to install a library

Tags: c++, macos, boost, terminal

I'm trying to install a C++ library (HElib) in OSX, according to it https://github.com/shaih/HElib/blob/master/INSTALL.txt.
When I use the `make` command, it saying `fatal error: 'tr1/memory' file not found`:

```
g++ -g -O2  -c NumbTh.cpp
In file included from NumbTh.cpp:16:
./NumbTh.h:71:10: fatal error: 'tr1/memory' file not found
```

I installed the boost library (using homebrew) and it locate at `/usr/local/include` and it contains that exact file, but still get that error every time.
What can I do?

Comment: Can you post the contents of file NumbTh.h between lines 67 and 75?

Comment: #if (__cplusplus>199711L)
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>
#else
#include <tr1/memory>
#include <tr1/unordered_map>
using namespace tr1;
#endif

Comment: I looked at the install instructions and there is no mention of boost. I don't think it is relevant here. This link (http://tinyurl.com/nkq56hw) could be useful. Also which compiler are you using? You can figure out by typing g++ -version

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [line 71](https://github.com/shaih/HElib/blob/master/src/NumbTh.h#L71), you will see that it is doing a version test on `__cplusplus`.  Since the version test failed, it decided that you had an old compiler and needed to include `<tr1/memory>` instead of `<memory>` in order to get at some standard functionality.  (Most likely `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`, which were previously only available in TR1 headers.)

Therefore, you either need to patch HElib to do the right thing for your compiler, or update your compiler to a version that supports either `<tr1/memory>` or a modern version that supports `<memory>` directly.

See also the [documentation for `__cplusplus`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace).